# Add HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) in AWS Gateway (REST API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, hsts

Our security team wants all our Rest API on AWS to have HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header set, even though our api's are not called from any webpages.

I have found some use cases on setting response headers in Lambda response but most of our api's are linked to SQS or SNS. So i'm not sure how to add this response header in AWS API GW.

Can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to find a solution to add the strict Transport Security (HSTS) response header. I have done this through AWS console.

**Step 1:** Add the *Strict-Transport-Security* header under *Method Response* Status code.

[image]

**Step 2:** Under *Integration Response*, add the necessary mapping value for HSTS header. Attached is the sample i have tried with. The values has to be provided in single quotes(*'*).
[image]

**Step 3:** Verified the same on *securityheaders.com* website.
[image]

Comment: Any advice for proxy integrations?
The error message in step 2 is : 

    Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses.

Comment: @BryanStump For proxy integrations, you have to pass the headers in the Program Response rather than setting it in the API gateway. In your response payload add headers key to set these. Below is a sample response of my lambda.



{
            "statusCode": "200",
            "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Strict-Transport-Security" : "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    }
            "body": "",
            "isBase64Encoded": "false"
}

Answer (score 5):

When setting this using Cloudformation and the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` be aware to put these header values into single quotes in between double quotes.. (`"'my value here'"`)

e.g.

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: 200 response for stackoverflow
    headers:
      Content-Length:
        type: string
      Timestamp:
        type: string
      Content-Type:
        type: string
      Strict-Transport-Security:
        type: string
```

...

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  responses:
    '200':
      statusCode: '200'
      responseParameters:
        method.response.header.Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000'"
```

Comment: This works perfectly for Cloudformation, thank you